# Web api 2 - windows + client cert auth - is it possible?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication, client-certificates

I currently have an asp.net web api 2 site hosted in IIS secured with windows authentication. A requirement has now come in for us to support client certificate authentication in addition to windows, and I'm struggling to find out:
- if this is possible at all 
- if there are any working examples available

I thought might be able to add an additional owin middleware or messagehandler or filter, but can't see any existing ones that do this specifically for windows rather than just relying on IIS. I know thinktecture identitymodel can do client cert, but not sure if the two can be combined?

Example of forms +win that i thought might be similar is here https://techblog.dorogin.com/mixed-windows-forms-authentication-for-ajax-single-page-application-e4aaaac0424a

Answer (score 0):

Right so I managed to figure it out. Thankfully, if a controller returns a 401, IIS automatically adds the negotiate/ntlm headers, so if a user is on a windows browser, it will then automatically authenticate as usual. So with that in mind, to keep windows auth working, I:

- updated the site in both IIS and VS to allow anonymous AND windows auth
- added the [AuthorizeAttribute] as a global action filter (which causes the 401 to be returned if the user is not authenticated by the time they hit the filter)

To get client certificate auth working, I used the magnificent [Thinktecture.IdentityModel](https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel) library, which allowed me to add only one line to my Startup.cs file (we're using OWIN so this was easy)

```
app.UseClientCertificateAuthentication();
```

See https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/blob/master/samples/OWIN/AuthenticationTansformation/KatanaAuthentication/Startup.cs for an example